# Upgrading Jenkins in a container loses SAML / SSO config

Tags: docker, jenkins, single-sign-on, saml, amazon-ecs

I am running Jenkins from the community Docker container image jenkins/jenkins:lts inside of Amazon ECS with persistent EFS storage on the backend for jenkins_home. Whenever I restart the ECS task for the Jenkins master, it loses it's SAML authentication configuration entirely. It looks like the rest of the config remains, jobs, history and such. I have to reconfigure SAML each time for authentication.

The SAML config files remain, however the config.xml is modified and the auth section seems to be removed.

How can I prevent a Jenkins container image from altering it's config.xml every time I launch a new container of it? I've tried using the environment variable JAVA_OPTS    -=Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false but that isn't working either.

Hopefully there is a simple solution to this :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer was a bit hard to find but this may help someone else -

A groovy script  /var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/startup.groovy was executing configureSecurity() on every restart. Took it out, now SAML remains and logins work post restarts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Disable CASC plugin, it will work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).